# When running the multiple python processes why does the second process not run until kivy has exited?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, kivy, python-multiprocessing

## Part 2

How can I get the two processes to communicate without writing to a text file as the interprocess communication?

## Part 1

My question is "When running the multiple python processes why does the second process not run until kivy has exited?"

`This part of the question has been answered by` @MikhailGerasimov

Before the moderators remove this question as a duplicate, let me give you some background.

### Background:

- I have built an application that has a GUI and an algorithm that happens in the background.
- I want them to run as two separate processes as the algorithm can take 10sec and is blocking the gui.
- To alleviate this, I run the GUI and algorithm in two separate python files that talk to each other via a text file, which is not ideal.
- Below is an extract of the code that I am using.
- When running the multiple processes why does the second process not run until kivy has exited? What is wrong in the code below?

Thanks for reviewing my question :-)

### Example Code

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import timeit
import glob
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import imutils
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.event import EventDispatcher

flag_path = 'status.dat'

Builder.load_string('''
<CameraClick>:
    orientation: "vertical"

    # STATUS BAR
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Button:
            id: statusBar
            text: root.nn_flag
            font_size: 40
            text_size: self.size
            halign: 'center'
            valign: 'middle'

    # EXIT BUTTON
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Button:
            id: btnExit
            text: "Exit"
            font_size: 40
            on_press: app.stop() 

''')

class CameraClick(BoxLayout):
    nn_flag = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CameraClick, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.nn_flag = 'Starting'

    def callback(self, dt):
        # Get Status of the algorithm
        try:
            with open(flag_path) as f:
                self.nn_flag = f.readlines()[0].strip()
                print('\n\nSTATUS:',self.nn_flag)
        except Exception:
            self.nn_flag = 'Empty...'

    def start(self):
        # Schedule File Polling
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.callback, 0.5)


class TestCamera(App):

    def build(self):
        widget = CameraClick()
        widget.start()
        return widget 

def saveToFile(mylist, filename='items.dat'):
    with open(filename, 'w+') as myfile:
        for item in mylist:
            myfile.write("%s\n" % item)

def runInParallel(*fns):
    proc = []
    for fn in fns:
        p = Process(target=fn)
        p.start()
        proc.append(p)
    for p in proc:
        p.join()


def doSomeWork():
    print('Starting NN....')
    # Load Images
    images = glob.glob('*.JPG')
    # Write to file
    saveToFile(['Applying function'], filename=flag_path)

    for idx, fname in enumerate(images):
        print('doSomeWork_'+fname)
        image = mpimg.imread(fname)
        image = imutils.resize(image, height=300)
        image = imutils.rotate_bound(image, 180)

    # Write to file
    saveToFile(['Done!'], filename=flag_path)


## MAIN
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start timer
    tic = timeit.default_timer()
    # Start Processes
    runInParallel( TestCamera().run(), doSomeWork)

    toc = timeit.default_timer()

    elapsed = toc-tic
    print('Elapsed time (sec)', elapsed)
```

Comment: `runInParallel( TestCamera().run(), doSomeWork)` - here you pass result of function call, not function itself. You probably wanted - `runInParallel( TestCamera().run, doSomeWork)`. I'm not sure about other things.

Comment: Do you really need to launch kivy core on a separate thread, or do you only want to execute the script in background, so kivy run on the main thread, and only communicate ?

Comment: @MikhailGerasimov, it worked. By removing the brackets after TestCamera().run() the two routines ran in parallel. Thanks!